# Is it possible to display a child border-bottom out of the parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm kinda confused and tried out everything I'm able to try. Searching stack overflow I couldn't find the similar problem. So a little background, I'm trying to make a navigation menu with flexbox like in the picture down below, but I can't display link's border-bottom out of its parent div. Is it even possible?

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUvQN.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #44433e;
}

.header__menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.header__logo {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu__item {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.menu__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #18cfab;
}

.menu__link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat-bold";
  color: #b8b8b8;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__link-active {
  color: #18cfab;
  
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
      <div class="header__wrap wrap">
        <nav class="header__menu menu">
          <div class="header__logo">
            Logo
          </div>
          <ul class="menu__list">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link-active">home</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">about</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">skills</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">service</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">work</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: a negative margin-bottom to li can do it

Comment: @johannchopin I said negative margin-bottom not negative border-bottom (and for all the li elements)

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do u mean by margin-bottom? just add margin-bottom to <a>tag or what?

Comment: *negative margin-bottom to li*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using an `:after` element with a `position: absolute`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #44433e;
}

.header__menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.header__logo {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu__item {
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.menu__item:first-child:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #18cfab;
}

.menu__link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat-bold";
  color: #b8b8b8;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__link-active {
  color: #18cfab;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__wrap wrap">
    <nav class="header__menu menu">
      <div class="header__logo">
        Logo
      </div>
      <ul class="menu__list">
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link-active">home</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">about</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">skills</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">service</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">work</a></li>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: omg you're the best one. Thanks for the answer you solved my problem ^^

Comment: @h0sang1 No problem ;)